# How to check modules and ensure mine are properly installed? IDLE cannot locate math module

Tags: python

```
from random import randint

word_bank = []

cat = str(input())
print('\nWord Bank:', *alpha)
    
word_bank = ['-'.join(alpha)]

def get_phrase(category):
    if category == "people" or "People":
        text_file = open("People.txt")
        line = random.randint(20)
        phrase = text_file.readline(line)
        print(phrase)
```

This is my code. After messing around I get a variety of errors include. It seems IDLE cannot find the math module. I am very new to this am not sure how to troubleshoot.

Thank you!

Comment: what is the error that you are facing? Copy and paste it alongside the question.

Comment: To get a list of available modules, type help('modules') in the interactive mode of the idle and press enter.